# node/expressjs mvc CRUD

Tags: node.js, express

In context of Node (or better expressjs!)

Is there any framework/tool which can generate  model,view,controller for basic crud operations + validations (like non-empty,defined,isEmail,Gender etc) for given table schema in popular RDBMS (or mongo?)

Answer (score 1):

Note from the future: By far the best solution for rails-like development in node is [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org). It's based on express, and the community is huge and still growing.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [railwayJS](http://compoundjs.com/docs.html) but i prefer expressJS with models specific to the DB choosen and [angularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for client-side framework